# angular 6 "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError" in reactive form dynamic form validation add and remove

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am Using Angular 6 Reactive Form if i add new validators add and remove in dynamically  i got a error is

> `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value: 'disabled: false'. Current
>   value: 'disabled: true'`

**.ts File**

```js
Form: FormGroup;
_UserTypes: any[] = [
  { _id: '1', User_Type: 'Sub Admin' },
  { _id: '2', User_Type: 'Manager' },
];
ShowReportsTo: Boolean = false;
constructor() { }
ngOnInit() {
  this.Form = new FormGroup({
    User_Type: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
    Reports_To: new FormControl(null),
  });
}
UserType_Change() {
  const value = this.Form.controls['User_Type'].value;
  if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null && value.User_Type !== 'Sub Admin') {
    this.ShowReportsTo = true;
    this.Form.controls['Reports_To'].setValidators([Validators.required]);
    this.Form.updateValueAndValidity();
  } else {
    this.ShowReportsTo = false;
    this.Form.controls['Reports_To'].clearValidators();
    this.Form.controls['Reports_To'].setErrors(null);
    this.Form.controls['Reports_To'].reset();
  }
}
```

**.html file**

```html
<Form [formGroup]="Form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 Form_Select">
      <label>User Type :</label>
      <ng-select formControlName="User_Type (ngModelChange)=" UserType_Change()">
        <ng-option *ngFor="let Type of _UserTypes" [value]="Type">{{Type.User_Type}}</ng-option>
      </ng-select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 Form_Select" *ngIf="ShowReportsTo">
      <label>Report To :</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="Reports_To">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button (click)="submit()" [disabled]="Form.invalid"> Submit </button>
</Form>
```

if i remove the dynamic validators is working good

this error not affect my flow but throw the error in console

how to handle this error

Comment: is this happened when you call the `UserType_Change()` function?

Comment: yes `UserType_Change()` is a function

Comment: no that's not what I mean. I want to know, when `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error is happening. is it happened when you call the `UserType_Change()` function ?

Comment: Still are you facing this issue or expecting good solution?

Answer (score 0):

The content of a div with *ngIf causes the error. Try this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="ShowReportsTo">
   <div class="col-sm-6 Form_Select">
     ...
   </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: your solution not solving my error, my error position is `<button (click)="submit()" [disabled]="Form.invalid" > Submit </button>`

Comment: What is in submit()? Also you didn't mention which third party library you are using as ng-select. The error comes from there, probably

Comment: I have the same issue with @kathir . My issue is that I have a dynamic form array and as I push a new form into the form array, the parent formgroup will become invalid since some fields of the newly pushed form are required. And the same error is thrown. For a while, adding `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default` in the `@Component` made the error go away (for some reason), this time it did not solve the problem.